# Changing the width of hamburger menu

Tags: codenameone

How can I change the width of hamburger menu or side menu about the 50% of screen size? By default, the hamburger menu holds about 90% of the screen width but I need to reduce the size.

I tried to do so by changing the value of sideSwipeSensitiveInt and sideSwipeActivationInt in the theme constant but with no luck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use [theme constants](https://www.codenameone.com/manual/advanced-theming.html):

- `sideMenuSizeTabPortraitInt` - The size of the side menu when expanded in a tablet in portrait mode
- `sideMenuSizePortraitInt` - The size of the side menu when expanded in a phone in portrait mode
- `sideMenuSizeTabLandscapeInt` - The size of the side menu when expanded in a tablet in landscape mode
- `sideMenuSizeLandscapeInt` - `The size of the side menu when expanded in a phone in landscape mode`